# C equivalent of C++ pointer intensive routine

Tags: c++, c, pointers, embedded

The following code is used on an embedded target to save a struct (of type Config) to eeprom by accessing the individual bytes in the struct's location in memory and writing them to EEPROM. What is the C equivalent of this type of pointer usage?

```
int EepromSaveBlock(int ee, const Config& value)
{
    const byte* p = (const byte*)(const void*)&value;
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(value); i++)
    {
        EEPROM.write(ee++, *p++);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps use a function instead of a member function (`EEPROM.write()`)? Also, what does this have to do with pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int EepromSaveBlock(int ee, const Config* value)
{
    const byte* p = (const byte*)value;
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(*value); i++)
    {
        EEPROM.write(ee++, *p++);
    }
    return (int) i;
}
```

Comment: Why the cast to `(int)`? And in what does this differ from the code OP posted?

Comment: Some compilers will moan if you return an unsigned int as an int.  Actually, the unsigned int should be a size_t because some compilers will also moan about that.